# Why can't TypeScript find name 'Express'?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm starting an express application using TypeScript.

Here's the code in app.ts:

```
import express = require("express");

let app: Express = express();
```

I have installed Express using

```
npm install --save express
```

And I've installed @types/express using:

```
npm install --save @types/express
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code (1.10.2).
When I hover over the express() function, intellisense suggests that it returns an object of type "Express". So, I've declared the "app" variable as that type, but VS Code puts a red squiggly under it and complains it "cannot find name 'Express'".

Why can't it find it? Or is that the wrong type? If so, why does the intellisense suggest it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear the variable should actually be of type express.Application.

```
let app: express.Application = express();
```